# Ошибка перемещения объекта при свайпе. Unity

Tags: unity3d-android

*Необходимо, чтобы объект при свайпе перемещался равномерно на определённое расстояние. А именно просто по оси y на 3 единицы. Вроде кодю верно. Объект движется. Но всё время на разное расстояние по оси y. То на 0.5, то 0.4, то 0.6, но никак не на 3 единицы. Не понимаю в чём ошибка. Если кто-нибудь знает, подскажите, пожалуйста*

```
void Update()
{
  swipePlayer();
}
```

```
public void swipePlayer()
{
 if (Input.touchCount > 0)
 {
  Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
  if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
      swipeStartTime = Time.time;
      startSwipePosition = touch.position;
    } else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
      swipeEndTime = Time.time;
      endSwipePosition = touch.position;
      swipeTime = swipeEndTime - swipeStartTime;
      swipeLength = (endSwipePosition - startSwipePosition).magnitude;
  if (swipeTime < maxSwipetime && swipeLength > minSwipeDistance)
     {
      swipeControl();
     }
    }
 }
}
```

```
public void swipeControl()
{
  Vector2 Distance = endSwipePosition - startSwipePosition;
  float xDistance = Mathf.Abs(Distance.x);
  float yDistance = Mathf.Abs(Distance.y);

  if (yDistance > xDistance)
  {
    if (Distance.y > 0)
      {
         target = new Vector2(0f, transform.position.y + 3f);
         transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
      } else
    if (Distance.y < 0)
      {
         target = new Vector2(0f, transform.position.y - 3f);
         transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Так прямо в коде стоит умножение на Time.deltaTime. Она и вносит такие коррективы в значение. Уберить его и будет вам счастье. :)

Comment: Вы неимоверно правы. Спасибо Вам Большое:)